# Remove insert data of a specific table from mysqldump output (sed?)

Tags: bash, sed, grep, mysql

I have a huge mysqldump output and want to exclude the inserts for a specific table.

The file looks like this:

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `big_table`
--

INSERT INTO `big_table` ...
INSERT INTO `big_table` ...


--
-- Table structure for table `next_table`
--
```

How can I cut out those inserts that come between "Dumping data for table big_table" and the next "Table structure for table" The file is too large to fit in a text editor.

Comment: How large is the file? Also, are you cutting _all_ the inserts? Finally, are the commands in one line, or possibly divided in multiple lines?

Comment: The file is 1.9 GB. I think the inserts can also be multi line. Basically I want to cut everything between this two markers. I think it should be possible with sed.

Comment: Ah, so the "Dumping data for table `big_table`" with the `--`s and the "Table structure for table `next_table`" with the `--`s are actually in the file? Do you want to remove whatever is in between the two marks (including perhaps the "Dumping ..." part)? Or only the inserts?

Comment: Is there a multiline insert (IIRC it's dumped as a single line)?? If not, a simple `grep -v "pattern"` will do

Comment: @Shabaz: Yes, this stuff is in the file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I overlooked the fact that all the inserts of course start with the table name. So I can simply use

```
grep -v "INSERT INTO \`big_table\`" dump.sql > dump_stripped.sql
```

Answer (score 7):

One solution using `sed`. It searches for all lines between literals `-- Dumping data for table 'big_table'` and `-- Table structure for table`. And comment those lines that don't begin with `--`.

Assuming content of `infile`:

```
1
2
3
4
--
-- Dumping data for table `big_table`
--

INSERT INTO `big_table` ...
INSERT INTO `big_table` ...


--
-- Table structure for table `next_table`
--
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Run command:

```
sed -e '
    /-- Dumping data for table `big_table`/,/-- Table structure for table/ { 
        /^--/! s/^/--/ 
    }
' infile
```

With following output:

```
1
2
3
4
--
-- Dumping data for table `big_table`
--
--
--INSERT INTO `big_table` ...
--INSERT INTO `big_table` ...
--
--
--
-- Table structure for table `next_table`
--
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Great! But there must be a solution also with deleting those lines?

Comment: @Alex: Yes. Substitute `s/^/--/` with `d` to delete those lines between the range that don't begin with `--`.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in 4 steps:

1. dump the tables only, without data:
   `mysqldump -u [user] -p[pass] --no-data username_dbname | gzip database_tables_no_data.sql.gz`
2. dump the data without big table:
   `mysqldump -u [user] -p[pass] --no-create-info --ignore-table=dbname.table_1 --ignore-table=dbname.table_X username_dbname | gzip database_data.sql.gz`
3. create db and import creation with no data: `zcat database_tables_no_data.sql.gz | mysql your_db_name`
4. import data: `zcat database_data.sql.gz | mysql your_db_name`

Answer (score 0):

How about a workaround:

1. Backup the table you don't want to update (Rename it then recreate an empty version maybe)
2. Run the dump
3. Restore your table and **override** the one fed by the dump

I hope this helps.

Comment: I do not have the possibility to make a new dump. If I had I would use  https://github.com/amenk/SelfScripts/blob/master/mysql-stripped-dump